# spyOn function not called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a function

```
getList() {
        return this.listFactory
            .fetchList()
            .then((data) => this.generateDsisplay(data));
}
```

and already mocked the `fetchList` return

```
mocktListRepository.fetchList.and.returnValue(PromiseUtil.transformAsResolvedPromise(listPage));
```

but in my unit test still fails. I have no idea why. The test will call the `generateDsisplay`

```
describe('getList()', () => {
        it('should call generateDsisplay', () => {           
            spyOn(component, 'generateDsisplay');

            component.getList();

            expect(component.generateDsisplay).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you add reason where its failing?

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous method call `this.listFactory.fetchList()` needs to be synchronized in your unit test. Using `fakeAsync` and `tick` from `@angular/core/testing`, this can be done as follows.

```
import { fakeAsync, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
describe('getList()', () => {
    it('should call generateDsisplay', fakeAsync(() => {           
        spyOn(component, 'generateDsisplay');

        component.getList();
        tick();

        expect(component.generateDsisplay).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```

As an alternative, you may also try the `async/await` as follows.

```
 describe('getList()', () => {
     it('should call generateDsisplay', async () => {           
         spyOn(component, 'generateDsisplay');

         await component.getList();

         expect(component.generateDsisplay).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });
 });
```

Again another approach using the `done` callback.

```
 describe('getList()', () => {
     it('should call generateDsisplay', (done) => {           
         spyOn(component, 'generateDsisplay');

         component.getList()
             .then(data => {
                 expect(component.generateDsisplay).toHaveBeenCalled();
                 done();
             })
             .catch(err => fail(err));
     });
 });
```